# Need help to find previous year using windows Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, batch-processing

Hi need some help in finding the previous year, using windows batch code

the code I am using is

```
:: This is Code for D3
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& 
right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
SET "PREVYEAR=%result:~0,4%-%1%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
SET YEAR=%DATE:~-4%
set "filename=%mm%%dd%%yyyy%"
echo "E:\Data Loads Folder\SafetyAndSecurity\D3\QVD\*%YYYY%_%filename%.QVD"
echo "E:\Data Loads Folder\SafetyAndSecurity\D3\QVD\*%PREVYEAR%_%filename%.QVD"
pause
```

this gives an output

```
"E:\Data Loads Folder\SafetyAndSecurity\D3\QVD\*2017_11152017.QVD"
"E:\Data Loads Folder\SafetyAndSecurity\D3\QVD\*2017-_11152017.QVD"
```

I need some advice how can I find previous year, the output of variable PREVYEAR should be 2016

Comment: The `DOS` tag is not relevant.  This is not `DOS`.  Your batch file is creating a vbscript and then executing the vbscript.

Comment: ok thanks I removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Vbscript to do this at all. While it does help and even Powershell is a good idea you can do this all with WMIC and Batch.

```
@echo off

REM Get Date and Time regardless of regional setttings
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"

REM Set year month and day into its own variables.
set "yyyy=%dt:~0,4%"
set "mm=%dt:~4,2%"
set "dd=%dt:~6,2%"

REM Subtract year
set /a "yyyy-=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one line of batch

```
set /a "PREVYEAR=%date:~9,4%-1"
```

which sets PREVYEAR to 2016

Unlike Squashman I don't like Powershell, take a look at Ruby for a vbscript replacement.

In Ruby this would be

```
Time.now.year-1
#=> 2016
```

Comment: The only issue with your batch file code is that it is region dependent.  People in different countries have their date format in a different order.